# Not able to display image icon using tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, project, tkinter-label

I'm working on a project, I created my own logo and the logo should be displayed on the topframe(the frame with white background) but the logo is not getting displayed , a white background gets displayed instead:

code:

```
class FirstPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.configure(bg="#E2611F")
        top_frame=Frame(self,bg="#FDA170",width=900,height=100)
        top_frame.place(x=0,y=0)
        logo=PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\pavit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python programs\icson3.png")
        Label=tk.Label(top_frame,image=logo,).place(x=10,y=10)
        Button = tk.Button(self, text="Next", font=("Arial", 15), command=lambda: controller.show_frame(ThirdPage))
        Button.place(x=650, y=450)
```

output:
[in the picture][image: output]

Please help me out to place the logo correctly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function)

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria no :(

Comment: What do you mean by "no". If you tried to implement a solution then update the question with the new code you used :)